# Can't rebind ReadWriteOnce PVC after pod crashes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

I am using the Bitnami RabbitMQ chart to deploy RabbitMQ to my kubernetes cluster and namespace.

This chart uses a StatefulSet, defaulting to a size of 1, where each pod runs a RabbitMQ container and has a PersistentVolumeClaim for data storage. This PVC has its access mode set to ReadWriteOnly.

The problem I have is if I try to update the RabbitMQ release with `helm update`, the new pod that gets created can't access the existing PVC.

Beyond this, I am concerned that if a pod in the StatefulSet crashes, the new pod that gets created to take over also won't be able to access the data.

Should I change the way I am using the chart, or is there a way to manage this unbinding and rebinding of PVCs?